# Matlab Arrays Handling

Tags: matlab, math

How can i store the input from user in an array. Well in C++ we had to define array before usage or had to assign dynamic memory for unknow size. But here in this program when i take the input from the user in array, it stores the last inputed value not all values. What should i do.

```
for x=1:1:2
f=input('Please enter the frequency for Sinusoid Graph');
freq=[f];
end
disp(freq)
```

Answer (score 1):

At each turn round the loop you execute the statement:

```
freq = [f];
```

which sets `freq` to be an array containing the value `f`.  Try, instead, `freq = [freq f];`  And note that this may not be very efficient if freq grows large.

Comment: so is there any way of declaring array like we do in C/C++

Comment: you can pre-allocate the array a number of ways like `freq=nan(1,10);` to make a 1-by-10 array. Keep track of which element you're inserting each time through the loop (if `i` is your index, use `freq(i)=f;`

Answer (score 1):

```
%pre-allocate a 2 element vector

num_inputs = 2;    
freq=nan(1,num_inputs);
    %iterate from the start to the end of your freq vector
    for i=1:length(freq)
      f=input('Please enter the frequency for Sinusoid Graph');
      if(~isempty(f))
        %if a value was input, store it in freq
        freq(i) = f;
      end
    end
```

By pre-allocating your array you make things a bit more efficient, and you can also more easily change how many values you are asking the user to input, as you only define the length of the vector in one place.  You could also add some validation of the input, to make sure a number comes back, for example.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

I think tmpearce has it in the bag, sorry I misunderstood the first time I looked at it.  I'm correcting my answer, but it's going to look at lot like tmpearce.

```
% preallocate array
freq = zeros(1,2);
for x=1:1:2
  % prompt user for input
  f=input('Please enter the frequency for Sinusoid Graph');
  % make sure something got entered
  if( ~isempty(f) )
    % save the data in your array
    freq(x) = f(end);
  else
    % alert user about the problem and quit
    disp('You did not enter a frequency!');
    break;
  end
end
disp(freq)
```

Comment: any other way. because I don't know the basics of this code you wrote. Actually i am beginner.

Comment: @scorpion, np between tmpearce and my corrected code you should be sitting pretty.